# Is every pure set of permutations a group?

Tags: cryptography, permutations

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of permutations over a finite set $\mathcal{S}$, with  $|\mathcal{P}|$=$|\mathcal{S}|!$

$(\mathcal{P},\circ)$ is a finite group, where $\circ$ is composition.

A subset $\mathcal{Q}$ of $\mathcal{P}$ is defined as *pure* when $\forall (a,b,c)\in\mathcal{Q}^3, a\circ b^{-1}\circ c\in \mathcal{Q}$ (update: and $\mathcal{Q}$ is non-empty).

Any (update: non-empty) subset $\mathcal{Q}$ of $\mathcal{P}$ that is closed under $\circ$ is a (finite, sub)group, and is thus pure.

Is every pure set of permutations a group? If not except for trivial $|\mathcal{S}|$, what's a minimal counterexample? (Solved, see update below).

Any idea to determine if the set $\mathcal{Q}$ of permutations resulting from the cryptographic function [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) is pure, with application to the security of [3DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES), as asked in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8057/555)?

---

Update: a minimal counterexample occurs when $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of the 2 permutations of 2 elements; and $\mathcal{Q}$ is the set consisting of the single non-identity permutation, which is pure, but not a group.

[Marc van Leeuwen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18880/marc-van-leeuwen) states in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/369274/35016) that a pure subset $\mathcal{Q}$ of $\mathcal{P}$ (assumed finite) is a group iff it contains the identity. Proof in the not-quite-trivial direction: if $\mathcal{Q}$ is pure and contains the identity $e$, then

- by setting $a=c=e$, $\mathcal{Q}$ contains the inverse of each of its element $b$;
- by setting $b=e$, $\mathcal{Q}$ is closed under $\circ$;
- thus $\mathcal{Q}$ obeys all the properties of a group.

Even combined with the established fact that [DES is not a group](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48071-4_36), and that it would be possible to test/prove that DES does not contains identity, that does not seem to prove that DES is not pure.

Comment: What's a "pure" set of permutations?

Comment: @Gustavo Marra: see third paragraph of the question.

Comment: Ok I missed it the first time!

Comment: +1 for a correctly written and redacted question, with links and definitions. Alas, this is becoming very rare in this site...

Comment: The claim that any subset $\mathcal Q$ of $\mathcal P$ that is closed under $\circ$ is pure fails in two ways (that may be irrelevant to this question though): $\mathcal Q=\emptyset$ fails to contain the identity, and, in case $\mathcal P$ is infinite, for instance $\mathcal P=\Bbb Z$, certain "monotonic" subsets may just be semigroups, for instance the permutations of $\Bbb Z$ that add a constant${}\geq13$.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen: I fixed the question, adding the necessary "non-empty". Thanks for that too. Note: that I consider permutations of a _finite_ set was already in the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption that $\mathcal P$ is finite, a pure subset is a subgroup if and only if it contains the identity permutation$~e$ (and you only need instances with $c=e$ in the description of pure subsets to show this).

Comment: I see an (easy) proof; problem partly solved; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The empty set and all one-element subsets of $\mathcal P$ are pure.

Comment: Perhaps more interesting: Any coset of any normal subgroup of $\mathcal P$ is pure.

Answer (score 1):

$$Q:=\{(12)\}\subset S_3\;:(12)(12)^{-1}(12)=(12)\in Q$$

yet $\,Q\,$ is not a subgroup...